# Limit does not exist but I get lim=0, why?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

From what I understand the limit does not exist: $\underset {x,y \rightarrow 0,0} {\lim} \frac {x^3y} {x^6+y^3}$

However, at first I tried to calculate it and got $0$:

$x=r\cos(\theta),\ y=r\sin(\theta)$  and $\frac {(r\cos(\theta))^3\cdot r\sin(\theta)} {(r\cos(\theta))^6+(r\sin(\theta))^3} = 
\frac {\cos^3(\theta)\cdot r\sin(\theta)} {r^3\cos^6(\theta)+\sin^3(\theta)}$ and the limit when $r\rightarrow 0$ is $0$.

So what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Use ```\lim```, ```\cos``` and ```\sin``` for better formatting _e.g._, $cos(\theta)$ vs $\cos \theta $.

Comment: You are assuming the $(x,y)$ pair can lie only on a circle which is not necessarily true. Try finding the limit along the parabola $y = x^2$, $x \to 0$.

Comment: Using polar form and letting $r$ tend to $0$ you are only approaching to $(0,0)$ through lines.

Comment: What would happen if $r=\sin\theta\to 0$?

Comment: @Christoph Holding $\theta$ fixed means it's going through a ray. (sudeep incorrectly stated the issue was lying on a circle, when I assume they meant the trajectories are the rays transverse to the circles.) Since holding $\theta$ fixed yields a limit of $0$ while letting $\theta$ vary with $r\to0$ can yield different limits, the issue with OP's reasoning does indeed involve the assumption of taking limits along rays.

Comment: Alternative bad path is $y=-x^2$

Comment: I would let $y=x^3$.  Then the expression simplifies to $1/(1+x^3)$ which has limit $1$.